# Is Listening on notify of $q better than $broadcast in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

The angular community discourages the use of $broadcast, so I am trying to find alternate approaches. Need suggestions on validity of this practice.

```
var deffered = $q.defer();

var getPromise = function () {
    return deffered.promise;
};

var notify = function () {
    deffered.notify('Hello');
};

var listenToNotification = function () {
    getPromise().then({}, {}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

over

```
var notify = function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', 'Hello');
};

var listenToNotification = function () {
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function (event, data) { 
        console.log(data); 
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the impression that "The angular community discourages the use of `$broadcast`".  There isn't anything wrong with using `$broadcast`, the problem is that people use it in places that it isn't necessary.  Unfortunately, that's also what makes your question difficult to provide an answer to, since you haven't provided any context as to the actual purpose of trying to notify anything.

Comment: The code I am working on is highly modularised. One module in particular needs to be notified if any action is done on other modules by the User. Like if user opens any popup, I need to pause a video in the background.

Comment: Right, that seems like a reasonable use for `$broadcast`.  I'm not sure that it makes any sense to create a promise to use for that scenario, though....

Answer (score 0):

Angular is made to do CRUDs primary on ajax and one of its great feature is promises. But promises are not meant to raise an event like a broadcast.
Here is the main difference.

**Broadcast** is a thing you can register for a certain event in your code.
**Promise** is something waits until its done and notifies you.
So based on what you want to do Broadcast is event driven and promises should be used with your ajax calls